# Are these functions closures?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to understand if it use closures

```
function $scope(meElement){

    return obj = {
        write: function(txt){
            return document.getElementById(meElement).innerHTML = txt;
        },
        delete:function(){
            return document.getElementById(meElement).innerHTML ='';
        },
        color:function(col){
            return document.getElementById(meElement).style.color = col ; 
        }
    }

}


function init(){
$scope('games').write('hello world');
$scope('games').color('yellow');
}
```

I learn about closures in JS , and I try to write some code to be sure if i understand how to use closures , so in this example I use closure?

Comment: Yes, this code uses closures. The `meElement` variable is "closed over."

Comment: thank you so much! :) good day!

Comment: In theory every function is a closure in JavaScript. You could restrict this a bit and say that every function that has *free variables* is a closure.